# (Client) screen capture in meteor?

Tags: meteor, screenshot

Is there a way to get a screen capture (of the client screen) in meteor? I don't care whether it's available (once captured) on the client or the server - either is fine.

I saw something similar to this but it appeared to only work for a browser window. I'm looking for a screen capture of the client screen no matter what is active - even if there's no browser open - just as if the user hit the "PrntScrn" key then pasted into a jpg file and saved it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot do such things (calling unapproved OS functions) from code that runs inside of a web browser.
This is a deliberate design decision for web browsers, as one doesn't want scripts from the broader internet running arbitrary code on your computer.

Internet Explorer used to (not sure if still) provide "hooks" for Windows Update that involved an Active-X control that interacted with the OS.
They MADE the OS (Microsoft) so it was their prerogative, but it undoubtedly lead to some exploits...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html2canvas` for generating the screenshot. There is [a meter package too](https://atmospherejs.com/new3rs/html2canvas) for the same on atmospherejs. You can find the docs and examples [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Alternative is to use PhantomJS to do this job.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ankit. I saw something similar to this but it appeared to only work for a browser window. Html2canvas looks like the same kind of thing- "This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser." I'm looking for a screen capture of the client screen no matter what is active - even if there's no browser open - just as if the user hit the "PrntScrn" key then pasted into a jpg file and saved it somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in meteor. You will probably require the user to install some script (like we used to have with facebook video chat some years ago). Anyway, Please add the additional details in the questions so that more people can respond to it.

Comment: I think you've just confirmed what I've suspected all along - that meteor is not really geared toward OS-level operations (things that happen independently of/outside a web browser.) That makes sense considering the limitations inherent in ES; I was just hoping those had somehow been circumvented in meteor.

Comment: Meteor is designed primarily for webapps, I am really not sure that making OS level ops will be in the meteor roadmap.